# Can I import "id" into "uid"?

Tags: feeds

I'm trying to import over 5000 users into drupal by using Feeds module. Can I import user "id" into "uid"? If so, how can I do that? I saw the GUID mapping target, but that is not "uid". Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not this is possible however in the past I've created an 'Original ID' field to hold entities ID's from legacy systems.

Comment: Does it has to custom script the Feeds module? I hope there is a way to add uid into a new target.

Answer (score 1):

The user ID field on Drupal is auto-incremented, so you don't want to import your ID values into that field. It's much better to add an *original_id* field to retain the legacy user IDs.

Comment: We need that for "created by" such user. If we not use the id into uid, then we have to modify over 800+ uid on articles, plus the issue with the double quotes database on body content.